# Laravel flash message can't close using close button and can't close by itself in a while

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Flash message stays in there and can't close by itself and button close. I use bootstrap and js for build flash message. This my code.

Controller, i put before redirect line.

```
Session::flash('flash_message', 'It has been saved!');
```

also, i have written `use Session` on Controller.

I made flash_message.blase.php

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
  <div class="alert alert-success {{ Session::has('penting') ? 'alert-important' : '' }}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

flash_message.blade.php has been included on index.

This the js code:

```
$('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).slideUp(300);
```

js code has been written as script on my main template.

Why can't those work? How to fix it?

Comment: So the alert shows up, but doesn't disappear when you ckick the button, is that it?

Comment: Yeah, That is right. What happens? How do make it work?

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap javascript plugin? See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing

Comment: I've tried a few possibilities, it's still no change. still can't close.

Comment: I pretty sure that you did not load bootstrap javascript plugin. Check your page in using developer tool, maybe some error logged in your console.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong writing the js file in the template. Thank you for showing it!

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong>
            {!! session()->get('success') !!}
        </strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, without any issues.

```
@if(isset($errors))
    @if(count($errors) >0 )
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                {{$error}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```